# MongoDb and POSTMAN: Document isn't being added to collection

Tags: mongodb, http, mongoose, https, postman

I am getting-started with mongodb.
I have set-up all the mongodb and the mongoose configuration and they work perfectly.
Here are the project files:

> server.js:

```
const TableRow = require('./models/tableRow');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/table', function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log('Successfully connected');
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});
app.use('/', router);
router.route('/table/add').post((req, res) => {
  let tableRow = new TableRow (req.body);
  tableRow.save()
      .then(issue => {
          res.status(200).json({'tableRow': 'Added successfully'});
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send('Failed to create new record');
      });
});
app.listen(5757, () => console.log(`Express server running on port 5757`));
```

> tableRow.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let TableRow = new Schema({
    column1Data: {
        type: String
    },
    column2Data: {
        type: String
    }
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('TableRow', TableRow);
```

When I tried testing this with POSTMAN:
[image]

I get this as you see in the response body:

> {
>       "tableRow": "Added successfully" }

Since in server.js, I have this code:

```
router.route('/table/add').post((req, res) => {
  let tableRow = new TableRow (req.body);
  tableRow.save()
      .then(issue => {
          res.status(200).json({'tableRow': 'Added successfully'});
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send('Failed to create new record');
      });
});
```

I thought that should do the work. However when I type:

> db.table.find()

I see that the table is empty. Any idea why?
Thank you!

Comment: aren't you sending simple text to DB? then use form content `x-www-form-urlencoded`  and also add this line to parse form data `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))`. But if you have to send large binary data (like multipart), the form-data is for that

Comment: If I use that I get this error: ObjectParameterError: Parameter &quot;obj&quot; to Document() must be an object, got ahmed

Comment: 2nd one is not going you mean? Did you select the `x-www-form-urlencoded` then send datas?

Comment: yes! It worked and it didn't work. I do get this on the console: { column1Data: 'ahmed', column2Data: 'ghrib' } but the document still doesn't get inserted in the database and I get that error

Comment: Actually No I no longer get that error for some reason. But the database is still empty

Comment: This is the object that gets inserted: {"_id":"5d08c3542d2b522454de0b97","__v":0}

Comment: did you add this line `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))`  below your `app.use(bodyParser.json());` ?

Comment: Ooops sorry thanks it's solved now :D

Comment: Can you please explain in detail when do I have to use form-data?

Comment: most of the time we use form data in postman for uploading files. I mean when our content type is multipart/form-data